# How to get DXGI_ERROR description?

Tags: error-handling, directx, directx-12

In a D3D12 program, I encounter a `DGXI_ERROR` (`CreateSharedHandle` returns an `int` `<0`), but I could not find a way to translate it into the "error description" or "error name" (or both).

I have a description by Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/dxgi-error

Is there such function out there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For development purposes, the "Error Lookup Tool" in Visual Studio can tell you the translation and code from a value.

You can also enable "DXGI Debugging" which will provide more information about error cases in the debug output window for your debug builds. See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/dxgi-debug-device/).

Programmatically, you can do it with [FormatMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-formatmessage) on Windows 10:

```
LPWSTR errorText = nullptr;
DWORD result = FormatMessageW(
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER, nullptr, hr,
    MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
    reinterpret_cast<LPWSTR>(&errorText), 0, nullptr );
if (result > 0)
{
    // errorText contains the description of the error code hr

    LocalFree( errorText );
}
else
{
    // Error not known by the OS
}
```

See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/wheres-dxerr-lib/).